# Validating an xml against xsd that was used to generate Beans

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I generate some beans from a couple of xsd via ant-build.

When unmarshalling an xml, I would like to validate that one. As far as I know, there is now way to do this with the beans themself, one has to do something like this:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Bean.class);
SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("whatever.xsd"));

Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
unmarshaller.setEventHandler(validationHandler);

return (Bean) unmarshaller.unmarshal(givenXmlString);
```

My problem is that `new File("whatever.xsd")`. I don't want to hardcode an URL to the xsd, that might change later (i.e. by refactoring the project) and will break at runtime, because one forgot (or didn't know) to change that url.

**Idea:**
The only idea I have for that is to copy the xsd to the same folder as the generated beans and to use the packagename of one bean to generate the url at runtime.

**Any better ideas?**

Comment: Could you put all xsd involved for validation into external `properties`.

Comment: @Xstian: Do you say to place the url to the xsds in a property-file?  I updated my post to explain why this would not help: _I don't want to hardcode an URL to the xsd, that might change later (i.e. by refactoring the project) and will break at runtime, because one forgot (or didn't know) to change that url._

Comment: You could use some hard coded default value and customize it by external property file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `sf.newSchema(File)` you can use `sf.newSchema(Source[])` with one of the `javax.xml.transform.Source` implementations, e.g. [javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html).